# Icomoon - Strokes get ignored when generating fonts. You can convert them to fills to prevent this

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I saved an Adobe illustrator file as an SVG file so I can upload it to Icomoon and generate a new font.

However, when I upload the SVG file to Icomoon, I get the following warning:

> Strokes get ignored when generating fonts.
>   You can convert them to fills to prevent this.

How can I convert strokes to fills in Adobe Illustrator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select all the paths and go to menu **Object** → **Expand**

Comment: Thank you Daniello. This is how I solved the problem. First I had to ungroup everything. Then I selected all paths and as you suggested selected Object -> Expand. Then I selected everything and selected Unite. Now it's working.
I'd like to know your comment about the way I have done.

Comment: I think Ungroup and Unite are unnecessary if the final objetive is transform it to a font, but it's a perfect way of making it.